# How to optimize this sub in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I got a sub that works well except it takes times to run and at the end, my excel shuts down.

```
Sub testing_rows()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nbTxt As Integer
    Dim I As Integer
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet4")
    
    gp_lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count
    
    For I = 2 To 100
        my_char = "-"
        nbTxt = (Len(Range("A" & I)) - Len(Replace(Range("A" & I), my_char, ""))) / Len(my_char)
        Range("BB" & I) = nbTxt
    Next I
End Sub
```

Where gp_lastrow = 28.000 lines and lastrow = 18.000
How can I optimize this sub which is only a small part of what I want to do... on almost 30.000 lines.

Thx

Comment: What is the expected outcome? Are you trying to count the number of hyphens (-) in all non-blank cells of column A?

Comment: Absolutely and put the number in column BB. I need to optimize for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading/writing cells always take some time. Several changes to improve efficiency:

- Load data into array
- Write output to sheet all at once

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008907)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [UBound function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1009050)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Sub testing_rows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, LastRow As Long
    Dim rngData As Range, i As Integer, arrA, arrBB
    Const START_ROW = 2 ' the first data row (skip header)
    Const IN_COL = "A"
    Const OUT_COL = "BB"
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ' load data on Col A
        Set rngData = .Range(.Cells(START_ROW, IN_COL), .Cells(LastRow, IN_COL))
        arrA = rngData.Value
        ' output range on Col BB
        Set rngData = .Range(.Cells(START_ROW, OUT_COL), .Cells(LastRow, OUT_COL))
        arrBB = arrA
        For i = LBound(arrA) To UBound(arrA)
            arrBB(i, 1) = UBound(Split(arrA(i, 1), "-"))
        Next
        rngData.Value = arrBB
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx a lot. That works so well & so fast ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Count Substring Occurrences

[image]

```vb
Sub CountSubstringOccurrences()

    Const REPLACE_STRING As String = "-"

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet4")
    
    Dim drg As Range, sAddress As String
    
    With ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        sAddress = .Address(0, 0)
        Set drg = .EntireRow.Columns("BB")
    End With
    
    Dim EvalFormula As String: EvalFormula _
        = "(LEN(" & sAddress & ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(" & sAddress & ",""" _
        & REPLACE_STRING & ""","""")))/" & Len(REPLACE_STRING)
    
    'Debug.Print EvalFormula
    
    drg.Value = ws.Evaluate(EvalFormula)
    
End Sub
```

### EDIT

**Refactored Using `Split`**

- The following is about 40% slower than the *Evaluate* version but it is stable i.e. the *Evaluate* version started to 'act out' while testing on a million rows i.e. a 'code execution has stopped' message would appear with no results or screen updating would get turned off (the results were there but not visible). No idea why.
- It was tested on my more than a decade-old machine (16Gb of RAM) running Windows 10 64-bit and MS365 64-bit, taking about 1.8 and 2.5 seconds respectively.

**Main**

```vb
Sub CountSubstringOccurrencesInColumn()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet4"
    Const SRC_FIRST_CELL As String = "A2"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "BB"
    Const SUB_STRING As String = "-"
    Const MATCH_CASE As Boolean = True
    
    ' Reference the workbook, the worksheet and the ranges.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = RefSingleColumnRangeEnd(ws, SRC_FIRST_CELL)
    If srg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = srg.EntireRow.Columns(DST_COLUMN)
    
    ' Return the values from the source range in a 2D one-based array.
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = GetColumnValues(srg)
    
    ' Return the counts in the destination range.
    drg.Value = GetColumnElementSubstringsCount(sData, , SUB_STRING, MATCH_CASE)
    
End Sub
```

**Help**

```vb
Function RefSingleColumnRangeEnd( _
    sourceWorksheet As Worksheet, _
    FirstCellAddress As String) _
As Range
    Dim rCount As Long
    With sourceWorksheet.Range(FirstCellAddress)
        rCount = sourceWorksheet.Cells(sourceWorksheet.Rows.Count, .Column) _
            .End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If rCount < 1 Then Exit Function ' no data
        Set RefSingleColumnRangeEnd = .Resize(rCount)
    End With
End Function
```

```vb
Function GetColumnValues( _
    sourceRange As Range, _
    Optional ColumnIndex As Long = 1) _
As Variant()
    Dim Data() As Variant
    With sourceRange.Columns(ColumnIndex)
        If .Rows.Count = 1 Then
            ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
        Else
            Data = .Value
        End If
    End With
    GetColumnValues = Data
End Function
```

```vb
Function GetColumnElementSubstringsCount( _
    SourceData As Variant, _
    Optional ColumnIndex As Long = 1, _
    Optional Substring As String = " ", _
    Optional MatchCase As Boolean = False) _
As Long()
      
    Dim CompareMethod As Long: CompareMethod = MatchCase + 1
    
    Dim dData() As Long: ReDim dData(1 To UBound(SourceData, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    Dim Value As Variant, r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(SourceData, 1)
        Value = SourceData(r, ColumnIndex)
        If IsNoErrorNoBlank(Value) Then
            dData(r, 1) = UBound(Split(Value, Substring, , CompareMethod))
        End If
    Next r

    GetColumnElementSubstringsCount = dData

End Function
```

```vb
Function IsNoErrorNoBlank( _
    Value As Variant) _
As Boolean
    If Not IsError(Value) Then
        If Len(Value) > 0 Then IsNoErrorNoBlank = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your help. But I get 1 on each line... I will try to figure out why.